# For loop issue in scala spark case

Tags: scala, for-loop, apache-spark, scala-collections

Looking to compare field by field of rdds by key and trying to populate the unmatched array fields but unable to use for loop.

below code wherein for loop is commented is working for 1st field check but I wanted to use for loop to cover all fields comparison

Any idea how to make that for loop work so that all the fields in a,b which are not equal can be populated ?

```
---a is of String type
---b is of Array[String] type
---c is of Array[String] type

var i=0
val joinedrdd = rdds1.join(rdds2)
val res= joinedrdd.map {
    case (a, (b, c)) => (
    //for (i <- 0 until (b.length - 1)){
        if (b(i).toString != c(i).toString)
        {(a, b(i), c(i))}
    //}
    )
}
```

Comment: What's the criteria to populate those values?

Answer (score 1):

There may be other more efficient approaches I don't know. However, I would `zip` both internal `Array`s and then `map` those values to find if they differ and if that is the case replace the returned value otherwise return the value.

```scala
jrdd.map {
  case (id, (xs, ys)) => (id, xs.zip(ys).map {
    case (x, y) if x == y => x // if x = y return x or y
    case _ => "random" // if they differ then return random
  })
}
```

You can see/test what I did just [here](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/2485090270202665/3702065294292299/8589256059752547/latest.html).

Comment: thanks Alberto, I was looking for almost the same as your sample code. But if there any way that we can ignore or avoid populating elements for case _ => "random"    ??

I just require only the elements which are not equal and ignore all the equal elements.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show me an example please. The description is pretty vague

Comment: Never mind.. I got that corrected. Thanks for your time and help here.. :)